# Papers on Dutch Disease

Tags: reference-request, dutch-disease

I am looking for papers on Dutch disease. Especially interested in Venezuela, UK, Colombia, Norway. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of suggestions:

- Acosta, P.A., Lartey, E.K.K. & Mandelman, F.S. (2009): Remittances and the Dutch Disease
- Bresser-Pereita, L.C. (2008): The Dutch Disease and its neutralization: a Ricardian approach
- Ismail, K. (2010): The Structural Manifestation of the 'Dutch Disease’: The Case of Oil Exporting Countries
- Larsen, E.R. (2006): Escaping the Resource Curse and the Dutch Disease?
  When and Why Norway Caught Up with and Forged Ahead of Its Neighbors
- Matsen, E. & Torvik, R. (2005): Optimal Dutch disease
- Roemer, M. (2015): Dutch Disease in developing countries: swallowing bitter medicine in The Primary Sector in Economic Development (Routledge Revivals): Proceedings of the Seventh Arne Ryde Symposium